# How does Windows File Explorer automatically refresh itself?

Tags: windows

Does it run in a loop polling the contents?
(Highly unlikely and inefficient.)

Or is it done with some event trigger?

In fact, what I am really wondering is how does Windows Explorer refresh itself when it shows the contents of another computer over a network?

How does the computer (or the OS) with the content notify the computer with the Explorer that its content has changed? If there is a mechanism to notify, what is the protocol? RPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this previous question:

[How does FileSystemWatcher work on another computers directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627068/how-does-filesystemwatcher-work-on-another-computers-directory)

It appears to be based on the [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx) API function.

Edit: [There is a Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx) detailing another way to do it, but the documentation for the specific functions imply that it might not work on a remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just out of curiosity or are you looking to do the same type of thing for your application?

If you just need to be notified of changes to folders in normal user scenarios consider [SHChangeNotifyRegister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762120(VS.85).aspx). if you're just curious or need a lower level hook, nevermind. :)