# How does MS Visual Studio determine that source file have changed?

Tags: visual-studio, file-io, compilation

Does it use modification timestamp or/and does it check whether the actual content has changed (e.g. by comparing the checksum)?

**Edit:** I need to know this since I use Git for source control and often change branches. It appears that sometimes even if I change the branch back and force (e.g. from *develop* to *master* and then back to *develop*), the VS rebuilds half of the sources files. I wonder why this happens and why does it happen sometimes and does not happen the other times.

Comment: What version of VS is this? What language are you using?

Comment: @ConradFrix VS2008, C++.

Comment: Those voting to close - programming tools are [on topic](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) on SO :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Visual Studio is a closed-source project, I bet only developers would be able to give a definite answer on how exactly does it work. However, for my purposes it is enough to test some scenarios.

I have tested it with a small solution and a couple of files in it (one header and two source files). Test results bring to the following conclusion. Visual Studio looks for modification date and time. Even if the file content is the same - it compiles this file and also any other files that include it. If the modification date and time are the same - it won't recompile it even if the content is different. Visual Studio ignores creation and access dates and times.

Comment: I just did some of my own tests because I wanted to know if it kept the modified time *per file* or *per build*. It appears from my testing it only keeps the last build time, then compares that to a file's last modified time. Thus it will only recompile if the file's modified time advances past the last build time. Even if it advances but not enough, it won't recompile.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it uses `FileSystemWatcher` on the project directories and linked files (if any), just because it's the right way to do this kind of thing.

Some googling finds for more about this class (or just look it up yourself):

- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-net-filesystemwatcher-object-to-monitor-directory-changes-in-c/6165137
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/filesystemwatcher

Of course when the source file is open, it's content by the time of editing, as wel as any user changes (even not saved) are loaded in the RAM, but it doesn't compare it to disk content (that'd be too slow), it listens to a system event when the system tells it the file changed.

**Update:**

Probably not that class itslf, but the Win32 version of it, you know most of the system related .NET functionality classes are just Win32 wrappers.

From this StackOverflow answer: [How does FileSystemWatcher work on another computers directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627068/how-does-filesystemwatcher-work-on-another-computers-directory/627137#627137)
I think it wraps this API (not sure): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465.aspx

**Update 2:**

This is Microsoft's approach to monitor file changes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chzww271(v=vs.80).aspx

**Update 3**

This is an old answer, and it was mentioned above that it was a guess, as Visual Studio is closed source as mentioned in other answers. It's worth mentioning that the **accepted answer** suggests Visual Studio looks for file modification dates instead, which suggests it doesn't use the approach guessed in this very answer, and that it was **wrong**.

I hope the reader didn't mind the effort given to rationalize possibilities in this answer (causing reader discomfort or down votes). Keeping it for archival reason only.

Comment: Isn't VS mostly Win32, aside from 2010's WPF user interface components?

Comment: Right, was just thinking of the approach generally. And even this .NET class is likely (like others) just a Win32 wrapper. Applied notes to post update.

Comment: This answer illustrates itself why questions asking for speculation are not constructive... what's the point of *guessing* what VS uses to do this?

Comment: But what happens if I change the files when VS is not active? Also as far as I know Windows caches frequently used files in memory and redirects all reads/write to this memory. The synchronization with hard disk is delayed to later time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I use Git for version control and often change branches. This causes some files to change timestamp, but not to change the actual content. I would like to understand how does Visual Studio handle this. From my experience it seems like it does it differently every time, which I don't think is what actually happens. Probably I just do not understand how it works.

Comment: So, the way I understand it is VS sets an event handler, windows detects the change and raises the event to VS. VS then will use Windows APIs also to read the file if it needs to. Note that VS doesn't load the files in memory unless they are open in tabs.

Comment: @Mohamed You continue to make *guesses* about this. That is not helpful, IMO. The OP wants a definitive answer.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't think that blaming users for what they write is an appropriate measure. If you feel that this question should be closed - please vote so. I will respect your vote, but please do not express that by blaming people. This will break their desire to answer questions. Perhaps the solution will be born out of speculation. Please do not respond here - we can continue on meta.stackoverflow.com: http://goo.gl/aP7qs.